# Django: work() missing 1 required positional argument: 'project_id'

Tags: django, sqlite

When I try to run the page /work/, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError at /work/

work() missing 1 required positional argument: 'project_id'
Request Method: GET

Request URL:    http://72.132.209.86:8000/work/ (Not my real ip)

Django Version: 2.0.5

Exception Type: TypeError

Exception Value:    
work() missing 1 required positional argument: 'project_id'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response, line 126

Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3

Python Version: 3.5.2
```

My code is:
views.py

```
def work(request):
    projectslist = Project.objects.order_by('project_name')[:5]
    context = { 'projectslist': projectslist, }
    return render(request, 'mywebsite/work.html', context)

def project(request):
    return render(request, 'mywebsite/project.html')
```

urls.py

```
path('work/', views.work, name='work'),
path('<int:project_id>/', views.project, name='project'),
```

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    project_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project_information = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    project_link = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    project_icon = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    project_category = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name
```

work.html

```
{% extends 'mywebsite/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <ul>

    {% for project in projectslist %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'project' project.id %}">Testtest</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

I do know that there is something wrong with the link, namely that it doesn't recognize the project.id, but I do not know what the origin is of this problem. The database that I am using is sqlite3 and I have two projects registered (on pk=3 and pk=4)

Comment: The error message in your post title (projectoverview() missing 1 required positional argument) is different from the error in the post (work() missing 1 required positional argument) - which is the correct one? Also the error in the post seems to refer to the `work()` view being called, and not the `project()` view - in which case the error is not being caused by the template code you have posted?

Comment: I have changed the title, that was indeed a wrong title, I added the project() view and url in because I also get the same error message when I try to visit for example /3/ (being the int value of a project, id = 3)

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a `project_id` parameter in your URL, but the view that handles it is not then accepting this argument - you need to add that argument to the function signature:

```
def project(request, project_id):
    # You probably want to use project_id here to create 
    # the context for your view.
    return render(request, 'mywebsite/project.html')
```

That said the exception you have posted is saying that it's the `work()` view that is missing this argument - so please check that the code you have posted above is exactly what you have in your project.

Comment: And how should I add the context, do I have to write: context = { 'project_id': project_id } or is it something else. I am following the tutorial of django, but this is the part that I don't have a clue what to do

Comment: Nevermind I indeed added a context and now it is working thanks for your time